# UISearchBar warning: UITextEffectsWindow should not become key. Please file a bug to Keyboard | iOS with this call stack

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar in a view which I am presenting using:

```
view.addSubview(searchView)
searchView.mySearchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
```

This works fine in most cases if I am simply typing the text into the search bar without touching it. However if I tap the searchbar (lets say to place the cursor at another spot or to copy/paste text etc), then Xcode prints the following warning:

```
[Assert] UITextEffectsWindow should not become key. Please file a bug to Keyboard | iOS with this call stack: (
    0   UIKitCore                           0x0000000190cd3e14 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 14769684
    1   UIKitCore                           0x0000000190a2e028 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 11993128
    2   UIKitCore                           0x0000000190c98ca8 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 14527656
    3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000190c77510 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 14390544
    4   UIKitCore                           0x0000000190c780c4 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 14393540
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00000001909e5d54 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 11697492
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00000001904d0f1c 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 6369052
    7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000190568a4c 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 6990412
    8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000190571fc0 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 7028672
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000019056ec48 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 7015496
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000019056e210 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 7012880
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00000001905627a0 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 6965152
    12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000190561b30 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 6961968
    13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000190a22534 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 11945268
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00000001909fd934 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 11794740
    15  UIKitCore                           0x0000000190a7fa20 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 12327456
    16  UIKitCore                           0x0000000190a841c0 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 12345792
    17  UIKitCore                           0x0000000190a7b480 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 12309632
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018e120240 F80FCA31-BF76-3293-8BC6-1729588AE8B6 + 631360
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018e120140 F80FCA31-BF76-3293-8BC6-1729588AE8B6 + 631104
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018e11f488 F80FCA31-BF76-3293-8BC6-1729588AE8B6 + 627848
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018e119a40 F80FCA31-BF76-3293-8BC6-1729588AE8B6 + 604736
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018e119200 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001a4214598 GSEventRunModal + 160
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00000001909df004 00EA1426-38F7-3FD2-BE01-04EBD44ECA35 + 11669508
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00000001909e45d8 UIApplicationMain + 164
    26  APPNAME                             0x0000000100423468 main + 88
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000018ddf8598 77E57314-8A58-3064-90C0-8AF9A4745430 + 5528
)
```

App doesn't crash but after this error, if I use Xcode's debugger to print the current keyWindow, it's set to `UITextEffectsWindow` (as the error warns about).

```
(lldb) po UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
▿ Optional<UIWindow>
  - some : <UITextEffectsWindow: 0x135ede920; frame = (0 0; 375 667); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x2815009e0>>
```

This causes any further view controller presentations using `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController` and `self.present` to fail as the keyWindow is `UITextEffectsWindow` and not my AppDelegate's window.

I am really not sure why this is happening. I am not messing around with keywindow anywhere in my app.

A workaround solution to fix this is that I can set the keywindow back to my AppDelegate's window by using:

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And things start working fine. However I would prefer to have a proper solution instead of this workaround. I think the `UITextEffectsWindow` is something which was introduced in iOS 13 to handle the gestures for handling Undo & Redo Typing etc but I could be wrong:

https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/undo-redo-typing-with-ios-13s-new-gestures-0201481/

1. Is there a way to prevent this?
2. If not, is there a way to disable the undo/redo gestures?

Note that this app was developed during iOS 11 I think and it doesn't have the SceneDelegate stuff (unless Xcode somehow added it when the project was upgraded).

**EDIT:** I found the following way to disable the iOS 13 gestures:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-disable-undo-redo-copy-and-paste-gestures-using-editinginteractionconfiguration

```
extension UITextField {
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    open override var editingInteractionConfiguration: UIEditingInteractionConfiguration {
        print("editingInteractionConfiguration!!!!!!!!!!!")
      return .none
  }
}
```

This does print my breakpoint but the `UITextEffectsWindow should not become key.` warning still gets logged in console. So maybe the issue is with something else.

Comment: Facing same issue while opening URL in external browser from the WKWebview in swift.

Comment: Still happening:

Comment: faceing same boblem in my chat appincation